# Jquery each in method

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, this, each

I have a class Playlist :

```
function Playlist() {
    this.episodes = [ /*episode list*/ ];
};
```

and I want to make a method displaying each episode :

```
Playlist.prototype.display = function() {
    $('.episodeList').each(function(index) {
        $(this).children('title').text(this.episodes[index].title);
    });
}
```

The problem is that the 'this' at the end, before '.episodes[index]' represent the dom object selected and not my playlist.

How can I solve this problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A common practice in Javascript is to make a new variable for storing the current class, since the content of the `this` variable changes with context. Consider something like

```
    function Playlist()
    {
        var self = this;
        this.episodes = [/*episode list*/];

        this.display = function()
        {
            $('.episodeList').each(function(index) {
                $(this).children('title').text(self.episodes[index].title);
            });
        }
    };
```

for your Playlist class definition, and call myPlaylist.display()
to display the content.

Comment: @user1540114 I assume you modified his code because it doesn't work the way he represented it. He is setting a global variable to the instance, so if you have multiple playlists it won't work.

Comment: That still won't work. `self` is only **local** to the constructor function, it is not available in `.display()`.

Comment: You're right, I incorrectly thought using the prototype was equivalent to the code I've edited to.

Comment: @Zach it's no longer using prototype and you lose the advantages it gives, such as sane indentation and method reuse.

Comment: @Esailija What's the best known solution to this problem, then? Bind or proxy or similar?

Comment: @Zach the each should take an argument for the context like `.forEach` but it doesn't. bind or proxy definitely look cleaner to me than this though.

Answer (score 1):

Bind the function to your context:

```
$('.episodeList').each($.proxy(function(index, elem) {
    $(elem).children('title').text(this.episodes[index].title);
}, this));
```

More on [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `each` on dom element, `this` inside each have reference to dom elements

For example:

```
Playlist.prototype.display = function(e)
{                                       
    $('.episodeList').each(function(index) {                                  
            console.log(this)                                       
    });
}
```

`console.log` prints dom element and it is correct.
Now put console log outside each like this:

```
Playlist.prototype.display = function(e)
{   
    console.log(this)                            
    $('.episodeList').each(function(index) {                                  

    });
}
```

Now `console.log` should print PlayList function (your class). So "this" in each scope have reference to dom elements but this in `Playlist.prototype.display` scope have reference to Playlist function.

Solution is:

```
Playlist.prototype.display = function(e)
{   
    var self = this;                            
    $('.episodeList').each(function(index) {                                  
        console.log(self)
        console.log(this)                   
    });
}
```

You need take "this" from Playlist scope and attribute to self var, so now self have refenrece to Playlist. Now you do each, so current this in each have reference to dom element but self variable still have reference to Playlist.

Answer (score -1):

In your code `$(this)=episodes[index]` because it's in the `each` function. I think this is what you want,

```
Playlist.prototype.display = function() {
  var element=$(this);

  $('.episodeList').each(function(index,item) {
        item.children('title').text(element.episodes[index].title);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why would you pass a normal object to jQuery (`var element=$(this);`). If you remove the call to jQuery, it should be fine.